# PHP convert mysql row into array to find its size

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, null

I've been searching for a few hours to find the right way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am looking for a way to count the number of fields that are NOT NULL in a defined row.

I would like to use mysql_query to convert the row into an array, skipping the empty fields. Then I want to take that array and find its size.

```
mysql_query(SELECT * FROM table)

$value = array(list, of, values, from, row, in, my, database);
echo sizeof($value); //value would be 8
```

I have also tried counting the fields using mysql_num_fields(), but don't know how to subtract the empty fields from the results.

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$num_rows = mysql_num_fields($test);
echo $num_rows; //but subtracting all fields that are NULL
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: im sure this could be dine via mysql, do you need the values as well or just the not null count?

Comment: you need to filter NOT NULL records?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL functions. Use PDO for MySQLi instead.

Comment: @Dragon - just the NOT NULL count

Comment: @timus2001 - I just need to get the number of fields that are were entered for any given row (skipping the blank fields).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way to clean arrays is to use php's array_filter function without a callback parameter. By default that function is set to remove elements that contain a false (or a 0), null or a "".

```
//This prunes out 'false', '0', 'null' or ''
$my_array = array_filter($my_array);
```

First store the mysql row into array and then filter it and then count element using cont function

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $row = array_filter($row); //remove empty values
   $num_of_values_non_empty = count($row);
   echo $num_of_values_non_empty;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. The code looks great and it looks like it should work, but I keep getting 10 as my result (which is the number of rows), but the total number of fields that are non_empty is 5. Any idea why that might be? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Try doing `print_r($row)` and ensure that the rows you think are empty are stored as a proper "empty" value. It's possible that they are not being stored as `""`, `null` or `false`, in which case `array_filter()` does not catch them.